# Why does not config(noreplace) create a .rpmnew file on upgrade?

Tags: rpmbuild

I'm currently testing installing a RPM with a config file using the config(noreplace) directive.

As per [using config(noreplace)](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s05s03.html)

My spec file marks a single file as a config file:

`%config(noreplace) /opt/lm/dest/conf/db.xml`

I did an on disk modification to the file for version 1 and proceeded to upgrade to version 2. I was expecting the verbose output to (when using -Uvh) to indicate that it has create a `db.xml.rpmnew` which it didn't however the on disk modifications I made are intact.

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Some background info: I am using the same tar file to create both version 1 & 2 which shouldn't make a difference but thought I'd mention it anyway.

Comment: your question is why it did not verbose creaing rpmnew? or why it created rpmnew file?

Comment: This was answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/672625/rpmnew-file-not-created-on-package-upgrade